# Do Pauli matrices correspond to rotations in R^3 like SU(2) matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, unitary-matrices

I am reading Andrew Steane's introduction to [spinors](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7ESteane/teaching/rel_C_spinors.pdf). I understand that rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ correspond to SU(2) matrices in the spinor representation, which are generated by Pauli matrices as $U = \exp[i(\theta/2)\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}]$. Given a unit spinor $\boldsymbol{s} \in \mathbb{C}^2$, I can find the corresponding vector $\boldsymbol{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\boldsymbol{r} = \boldsymbol{s}^\dagger \boldsymbol{\sigma} \boldsymbol{s}$ (Eq. 17.19). So I can plot $\boldsymbol{r}$ and see that $U$ yields a rotation.

Pauli matrices are unitary, but not SU(2). Because of that I would have expected that applying a Pauli matrix to a spinor $\boldsymbol{s}$ does not yield a rotation for $\boldsymbol{r}$. However $\sigma_1\boldsymbol{s}$ seems to be equivalent to a rotation of $\boldsymbol{r}$ about the $x$ axis, which I can represent by $U = \exp[i\pi/2\sigma_1] = i\sigma_1$.

So should Pauli matrices be considered rotations? All rotations can be expressed as SU(2) matrices, but there exist also non SU(2) matrices that correspond to rotations?

Thank you

Comment: The fact that $\exp(i\theta\sigma)$ is a rotation has nothing to do with the fact that $\sigma$ is unitary. Instead, this is a result of the fact that $\sigma$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Thank you Omnomnomnom . I have read that when using $\exp(i\cdot)$ the exponent should be Hermitian and traceless for $\exp(i\cdot)$ to be unitary. My concern is when not using this formula. Why is $M = \sigma_1 \neq \exp(i\cdot)$ also a rotation? Should it not be that if $M$ is a rotation, then it has to be writable as $M = \exp(i\cdot)$? Likewise are there other rotations that can be expressed not by the exponential formula?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\sigma_1$ is a rotation"? I agree that a rotation $r$ can be obtained from $\sigma_1$ (in the same way that a rotation can be obtained from any Hermitian operator), but this does not mean that $\sigma_1$ **is** a rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I am not expert in maths, so I am probably misunderstanding something and misusing terminology. Given an initial unit spinor $\boldsymbol{s}$, I can get the corresponding rotated vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by applying an SU(2) matrix built with the exponential formula and then using Eq. 17.19 above. I had (wrongly?) assumed $\boldsymbol{s}_1 = M \boldsymbol{s}$ corresponds to a rotated vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ only if $M$ is SU(2). From your remark, instead, should I expect that any Hermitian $M$ also corresponds to a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Thank you.

Comment: It is indeed true that if $s$ is a vector and $M \in SU(2)$, then $Ms$ is a rotation (in the sense intended by the author apparently). I don't see what this has to do with the statement "$\sigma_1$ is a rotation"?

Comment: Sorry, that should say "$M$ is a rotation and $Ms$ is the rotated vector".

Comment: OK, the statement "$\sigma_1$ is a rotation" is wrong and ill defined. I totally retract that. I have a unit spinor $\boldsymbol{s}$ and its corresponding vector $\boldsymbol{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. In the sense intended by Steane, I can rotate $\boldsymbol{r}$ by an angle $\theta$ along a certain axis using the $U=\exp(\ldots)$ formula. I wondered whether I can achieve the same using $M \notin SU(2)$.

Comment: I see. I would say that multiplication by a $(2 \times 2)$ matrix outside of $SU(2)$ cannot be called "rotation".